# Assign value to struct type constants in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I have following code which I guess is assigning a value to constant struct

in header file:

```
struct madStruct {
    uint8_t code;
    uint8_t cluster;
};
typedef struct madStruct MadStruct;
```

and in `C` file

```
const MadStruct madStructConst = {
    .code = 0x00,
    .cluster = 0x01,
};
```

I would like to know what what does this code supposed to do?

This code does not compile in Visual Studio C++ 2010, how can I convert it so I can compile in both MingW and Visual Studio C++ 2010?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax was introduced in C99 and allows the name of the members to be explicitly specified at initialisation (the `.code` and `.cluster` are known as *designators*). The initialisation assigns the value `0x00` to the `code` member and value `0x01` to the `cluster` member.

VC only supports C89, so compiliation fails. As the `struct` only has two members and both are being initialised you can replace the initialisation with:

```
const MadStruct madStructConst = { 0x00, 0x01 };
```

without the designators the members are initialised with the specified values in the order that the members are defined in the `struct`. In this case `code` is assigned `0x00` and `cluster` is assigned `0x01`, the same as the initialisation with the designators.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was guessing it is visual studio related thing.I was recently in Visual Studio 2012 launch event. they added lots of features to it but what is not changed is the compiler!! A Ferrari with WW Beetle 1945 engine!!